# How to keep track of Eigen objects through a solve()?

Tags: c++, eigen, expression-templates, temporaries

This question is related to [cast from Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp to MatrixXd causes segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21161392/958110) .
It will probably have as simple a solution as the former.

In this minimal example, I define `Holder`, which holds and Eigen matrix, and returns it via its `get()` member function. Similarly, `Decomp` is an expression template for the LDLT decomposition of this matrix, and `Solve` solves for AX=B, yielding X.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Cholesky>

template <class EigenType> class Holder {
public:
typedef EigenType result_type;

private:
result_type in_;

public:
Holder(const EigenType& in) : in_(in) {}
const result_type& get() const { return in_; }
};

template <class Hold> class Decomp {
public:
typedef typename Eigen::LDLT
    <typename Eigen::MatrixBase<typename Hold::result_type>::PlainObject>
        result_type;

private:
Hold mat_;

public:
Decomp(const Hold& mat) : mat_(mat) {}

result_type get() const { return mat_.get().ldlt(); }
};

template <class Derived, class OtherDerived> class Solve {
public:
typedef typename Eigen::internal::solve_retval
    <typename Derived::result_type, typename OtherDerived::result_type>
        result_type;

private:
Derived decomp_;
// typename Derived::result_type decomp_;
OtherDerived mat_;

public:
Solve(const Derived& decomp, const OtherDerived& mat)
    : decomp_(decomp), mat_(mat) {}
//: decomp_(decomp.get()), mat_(mat) {}

result_type get() const { return decomp_.get().solve(mat_.get()); }
// result_type get() const { return decomp_.solve(mat_.get()); }
};

typedef Holder<Eigen::MatrixXd> MatrixHolder;
typedef Decomp<MatrixHolder> MatrixDecomp;
typedef Solve<MatrixDecomp, MatrixHolder> SimpleSolve;
```

The following test fails on `X.get()`

```
#include "Simple.h"
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char * []) {
MatrixHolder A(Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(3, 3));
MatrixHolder B(Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(3, 2));
MatrixDecomp ldlt(A);
SimpleSolve X(ldlt, B);
std::cout << X.get() << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

but if you use the commented out lines in the header file, everything works fine. Unfortunately, this moves the evaluation of the decomposition to the construction of the solver, which is not suited to my use. Typically, I want to build a complicated expression `expr` involving this `Solve`, and call `expr.get()` later on.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a general rule to follow, to avoid further related questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid useless and expensive copies, the internal `solve_retval` structure stores the decomposition and right-hand-side by const references. However, the `LDLT` object created in the `Decomp::get` function is deleted at the same time this function returns, and thus the `solve_retval` object references dead objects.

One possible workaround, is to add a `Decomp::result_type` object in `Solve`, and initialize it in `Solve::get`. Moreover, to avoid multiple deep copies, I suggest to use const references for a few attributes as follow:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Cholesky>

template <class EigenType> class Holder {
public:
  typedef EigenType result_type;

private:
  result_type in_;

public:
  Holder(const EigenType& in) : in_(in) {}
  const result_type& get() const { return in_; }
};

template <class Hold> class Decomp {
public:
  typedef typename Eigen::LDLT
      <typename Eigen::MatrixBase<typename Hold::result_type>::PlainObject>
          result_type;

private:
  const Hold& mat_;
  mutable result_type result_;
  mutable bool init_;

public:
  Decomp(const Hold& mat) : mat_(mat), init_(false) {}

  const result_type& get() const {
    if(!init_) {
      init_ = true;
      result_.compute(mat_.get());
      return result_;
    }
  }
};

template <class Derived, class OtherDerived> class Solve {
public:
  typedef typename Eigen::internal::solve_retval
      <typename Derived::result_type, typename OtherDerived::result_type>
          result_type;

private:
  const Derived& decomp_;
  const OtherDerived& mat_;

public:
  Solve(const Derived& decomp, const OtherDerived& mat)
      : decomp_(decomp), mat_(mat) {}

  result_type get() const {
    return decomp_.get().solve(mat_.get());
  }
};
```

The general rule is to store heavy objects by const reference (to avoid deep copies) and lightweight expressions by value (to reduce temporary life issues).

Comment: I guess it would make more sense to store this in the Decomp class. What about a generalization? When should I store? When should I pass as const ref?

Comment: I meant *store* as const ref vs store as value.

Comment: right, I simplified the example and commented on the general rule in the above answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. When should we expect Eigen objects to store references to other objects that might break (like here)?

Comment: As I said, anytime the nested object is heavy, that is, a matrix or an object storing its own matrices.